# Combine min-width, min-height, max-width and max-height with child visibility

Tags: html, css

I'd like to keep an element (filled with some child content) between some minimum and maximum `width` and `height` relative to the container. Let's say that it should be not less than 10% and not more than 30% on width and between 30% and 50% on height.

Child should shrink to width or height, depending which limits it first.

Unfortunately for some reason only `max-width` seems to be considered when rendering. Height values don't matter. Why?

```css
.minmax {
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 50%;
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 30%;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.maxchild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="minmax">
<img class="maxchild" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/9d/db/74/9ddb7408078168b787aeb48b2c36d65a--quinoa-recipe-puppet-show.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use media screens?

Comment: Use vh instead of %. That should fix it considering that minmax wraps the entire browser screen.

Comment: _“Height values don't matter. Why?”_ - because heights given as percentages require an explicit height on the parent element, which you do not have here.

Comment: @friedman, seeing as it is the only solution given, if it helped your query rate it up and mark it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to something like this perhaps? I've also aligned the image inside horizontally and vertically depending on which dimension expands.

```css
.minmax {
  min-height: 30vh;
  max-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 5%;
  max-width: 10%;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.maxchild {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="minmax">
<img class="maxchild" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/9d/db/74/9ddb7408078168b787aeb48b2c36d65a--quinoa-recipe-puppet-show.jpg" />
</div>
```